# How to fill data in a base html file Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a base html file (for which code shouldn't be necessary) that requires some tags in the menu to be filled with id numbers (which are dynamic, and can't be hard coded). It seems to me that writing code to populate the tags for each view violates the DRY principle, and as such there should be some way to provide variables to a base html document. How does one do this, if it's possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. [Custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-assignment-tags)
2. [Custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Which way to use depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use Context Processor. Google "django context procoessor" it'll come up with many results.